# Why the TBT is "Unavailable" in ChromeDev Tools?

Tags: web-performance, web-vitals

The TBT might be "Unavailable" in ChromeDev Tools. Why is that?

[image]

Is that because the TTI cannot be calculated accurately? I guess maybe the recording from the performance timeline does not provide enough information to find out there is a five-mininute idle time to defined as quite window. Is it right?

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: @RickViscomi Version 92.0.4515.159